# expo cli log stack trace is always the same

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

My app has a few warnings and I'd like to handle but the logged stack trace is the same not matter the warning or error so I can't debug properly.

No matter if it is a sentry, a hook or a redux warning or error stack trace is always the same:

```
Stack trace:
  node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:156:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
  node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:26 in serializeLogDataAsync
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:39 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:21 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:20 in define$argument_2
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:39 in tryCatch
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:155:19 in invoke
  node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:190:10 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:4 in tryCallTwo
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:12 in doResolve
```

This is my env right now:

```
expo-env-info 1.0.2 environment info:
System:
OS: macOS 11.6
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.16.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node
npm: 6.14.12 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
IDEs:
Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882
Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ~43.0.2 => 43.0.5
react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3
react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1
npmGlobalPackages:
eas-cli: 0.47.0
expo-cli: 5.1.3
Expo Workflow: bare
```

Are you facing this issue right now? any hints or clues to solve and getting useful logs for stack tracing?